# Running a PHP files as root owned by other user, is it risky?

Tags: php, security, command-line-interface

I need to run a PHP file via the CLI.
This file is owned by a non-root local user (we'll call it "bob" => bob:bob). bob has uid = 1000, gid = 1000

And the file is as follow :

ls -l => -rw-rw-r--. 1 bob bob  173 29 may   10:46 file.php

I can only run this script as root, using the following :

```
php -d open_basedir="/home/bob" -f /home/bob/file.php
```

The php.ini file for cli contains restrictions regarding functions disabled, which are :

```
apache_child_terminate,apache_setenv,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,define_syslog_variables,dl,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,eval,exec,fp,fput,ftp_connect,ftp_exec,ftp_get,ftp_login,ftp_nb_fput,ftp_put,ftp_raw,ftp_rawlist,highlight_file,ini_alter,ini_get_all,ini_restore,inject_code,leak,mysql_pconnect,openlog,passthru,pclose,pcntl_alarm,pcntl_exec,pcntl_fork,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_wait,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_wtermsig,pfsockopen,phpAds_XmlRpc,phpAds_remoteInfo,phpAds_xmlrpcDecode,phpAds_xmlrpcEncode,php_uname,popen,posix_getpwuid,posix_kill,posix_mkfifo,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,posix_setuid,posix_uname,proc_close,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_open,proc_terminate,shell,shell_exec,symlink,syslog,system,xmlrpc_entity_decode
```

Now, the big question :

> **is it dangerous to call the file using root user ?**

I tested with `getmyuid()`, `getmygid()`, `get_current_user()` in `file.php` when calling it from root, and the data was correctly `1000`, `1000`, and "`bob`".

I would say it's safe, but I'm not 100% sure!

Thank you for your help.

(Note: I cannot run it through `sudo` because the user is created on the fly)

Comment: If you can be root, why not run it as "bob"? `sudo -u bob <whatever command goes here>`

Comment: What risk are you talking about ? Allow the file to be used by root if you get hacked is dangerous because file.php makes sensitive treatment ?

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but in order for that command to work, I need to add "bob" to the sudo configuration file right?

Comment: @CyrilN. no, if "bob" can run script, then another non-root user with the sudo privileges may run script as bob. So bob doesn't need to be sudo user, but the one who will run script "as bob" - does

Comment: How much do you know about this script? If the answer is anything less than 'everything' running it as `root ` is very risky indeed.

Comment: @Random `file.php` is written by the user `bob` and I don't have the possibility to verify what will be written. `bob` can be anyone and can do anything in this file. That's why I restricted it with some functions and the `open_basedir`. If I'm not mistaken, the only last risky point is from running the script as root.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I will know nothing (Jon Snow knows nothing). You could be Bob right now and write what you want in that file. Now, what could you do that could be harmful ?

Comment: So the problem is that you can't read file.php, but you would like to run it, and you want to be sure it cannot harm the server, so you disabled some function in php.ini, and you need to know if you forgot nothing, right ?

Comment: @HoboSapiens (You can answer my previous question about the risks as a true answer, I will accept it since it answers my question that it will be, indeed, risky)

Comment: One thing I could possibly do is install a backdoor user that might allow an attacker entry, or package up /etc/passwd and send it somewhere, or unmount the filesystem or...

Comment: @HoboSapiens How could you do that, since `open_basedir` restrict you to your local folder only, and (from what I saw using `getmyuid` and `getmygid`), you are identified as `bob`:`bob` ?

Comment: From what I understand, the situation is exactly the same as an hosting provider, except the call to php files isn't from a web request, but from the cli. So I am truly wondering what am I missing

Comment: @HoboSapiens I am truly interested to know what flaws could be present with my situation here. If there is ?

Comment: Why is it returning `bob` when ran by `root`?

Comment: @SilverlightFox That's a good question I was wondering too. Maybe the php executable runs it with the rights of the owner/group of the file, not the user running the executable? I miss some knowledge on that but it would resolve parts of my solution which it would be more secure then.

Comment: @CyrilN. It shouldn't unless the SUID bit is set on `php` binary. I can't recreate the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: That's odd, the SUID is not set : `-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4391896 16 mai   09:32 /usr/bin/php`